# How to send cookie in each request header in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am in developing Angularjs web application. I am using API's to get data. On login successful i will get some data in cookie(response header). In very next subsequent http calls i need to send that back cookies data to apis. Below is the snapshot of response header.

[image: Response header with cookie]

Below is my sample $http call.

```
var req = {
              method: 'POST',
              url: savepersonaldetailsurl,
              headers: {
              RequestedPlatform: "Web",
              RequestedLanguage: cookiePreferredLanguage
              },
  data:      {
             LoginId: LoginID
             }
   $http(req).then(function (response) {
   //do something here
  }, function (error) {
     toastr.error($filter('translate')('Error Occured'));
     });
```

On each http call i want to send cookie in header. May i know how this can be done in angularjs? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Cookies send and received by server for each call, why handle it in client side code?

Comment: Shouldn't this happen anyway? Afaik, the browser will append valid cookies to any subsequent request to the same domain anyway.

Comment: Thank you Chris G. So no need to manually attach cookies right?

Comment: In my case cookies are not sending in subsequent requests. Do i need to enable anything?

Answer (score 1):

One of the features of Cookies is that they're sent to the server with each request. Make sure that the domain the request is being made to is the same domain that set it or a sub domain.

> The cookie is usually stored by the browser, and then the cookie is
>   sent with requests made to the same server inside a Cookie HTTP header
>   -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole did this help you?

Answer (score 1):

First store the value which comes from response in localstorage then secondly you can make a common global functions which set the value to localstorage and get the value and call that function on every request.

for example:-

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': authfunction.getToken('AuthToken');
}
```

In this example i set the value in local storage named AuthToken and while passing it we get and set it.

Comment: Thank you Jaimin. How can i read cookies from the response? Is there any function to read it?

Comment: I tried as below and i am getting undefined eventhough i can see cookie in response.   var cookievalue = $cookies.get('CookieHeaders');
            console.log(cookievalue);